# How to share sql server 2008R2 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to **share my SQL Server 2008 R2 database between some computers on the same network** without using a Server. How can I do so? I mean i just want two users access the same Database through A network or LAN. Both can use database,update database,delete data from database
**is it possible ?**

Comment: What do you mean with "without using a Server"?

Comment: Cant we set it as Linked Server?

Comment: It's already called SQL **Server** - why do you think this is the case? If you want to share - you have to use a **server** - that's the only viable way to do it. Get over it. Set it up. It's really easy, and no problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file: **mdf** MS SQL  can not be shared directly.

Although, once installed MS SQL any user with privileges on the database can access it.

It is not necessary to share the MDF file. MS SQL is responsible "sharing" the users enter data accessing it.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can only be installed on a Windows Server system (except for the Developer's edition, and SQL Express).

However, all versions (except CE) can be shared among multiple clients.   Just start up the server, make sure that the TCP protocol is enabled (using the SQL Server Configuration Tool), and that your Windows Firewall is not blocking port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

A server just happens to be a term used for otherwise a "normal" computer. The designation server usually means that it is dedicated for a certain task. Technically speaking, any computer can be a server--even your own workstation while you are using it for other tasks. So, just put the database on one of the user computers which is on the network (hence accessible to desired users on the network) and go for it.... Good luck!

Comment: Well, while what you point might be true in some cases, you must remember that mostly all editions of SQL Server require a Windows Server OS as installation requisite.

Comment: @Oscar Data Center, Web, and Enterprise require a Server OS. Standard, Workgroup, developer and express can be installed on workstations.  So 3 out of 7 isn't exactly *mostly all*. see [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx)